# SML Pattern matching throwing "types of rules don't agree [tycon mismatch]" error

Tags: pattern-matching, sml

```
fun sample(list_of_str_lists, s) =
    case list_of_str_lists of
           [] => []
        | x::[] => case (all_except_option(s, x)) of
                        SOME lst => lst
                      | NONE => []
        | x::xs' => case (all_except_option(s, x)) of
                        SOME lst => lst @ sample(xs', s)
                      | NONE => [] @ sample(xs', s)
```

It uses a helper function that takes a list of strings and returns all elements in that list in an `list option` if there is a matching string in that list (again, excluding the matching string). So the helper function will take a list `["a", "b", "c"]` and a string `"a"` and if it matches `"a"`, will return an option containing `["b", “c”]`.

My problem is in `sample` in the last pattern matching branch. It throws the error

```
earlier rule(s): 'Z list option -> 'Z list
  this rule: string list list -> string list
  in rule:
    :: (x,xs') =>
      (case (all_except_option (s,x))
        of SOME lst => lst @ sample <exp>
         | NONE => nil @ sample <exp>
```

but I don’t understand why, because the pattern I’m trying to match calls for `SOME lst` but it’s describing it as `string list list`. What’s going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a syntax issue due to the nested `case` expressions. The parser assumes that the case `| x::xs' => ...` is a continuation of the ongoing case expression `case (all_except_option(s, x)) of ...` since it has no way of telling it's actually meant to belong to the enclosing expression `case list_of_str_lists of ...`.

If you enclose the inner case expressions in parentheses, the function definition will parse.

```
fun sample(list_of_str_lists, s) =
  case list_of_str_lists of
    []     => []
  | x::[]  => (case (all_except_option(s, x)) of
                 SOME lst => lst
               | NONE     => [])
  | x::xs' => (case (all_except_option(s, x)) of
                  SOME lst => lst @ sample(xs', s)
                | NONE     => [] @ sample(xs', s))
```